# BDD Given - How do you set the starting page?

Tags: bdd, katalon, gherkin

```
Given user is currently at Login page
```

With the Given above it would be invalid if I include the actual navigation to login page in the step definition simply because navigating to a page is an action and should be included in When.. unless that's just fine... or is there any other way to do it?

```
@Given("user is currently at Login page")
def user_is_at_login_page(){
    WebUI.openBrowser('/login')
    WebUI.verifyElementPresent('Login Page Heading')
}
```

I'm using Katalon Studio btw

Comment: That is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Given is your setup, it brings the system under test in a state you can start doing the action you want to test.

> The given part describes the state of the world before you begin the behavior you're  specifying in this scenario. You can think of it as the pre-conditions to the test.
>
> https://martinfowler.com/bliki/GivenWhenThen.html

Depending on the complexity of the Given it will most likely do actions that other scenarios would do as a when.

Often my givens (for example: Given a fresh user is on page X) do the following in a single step:

- Clean data
- Create data and users
- Login user
- Navigate to the wanted state

I like to keep my Given, When, Thens as short as possible, they should describe the behaviour not the details.

Answer (score 0):

The Given statement usually fulfills both the test setup conditions of setup-action and setup-verification. However, in some cases it may not contain the setup action. So, it basically depends on your test and there is no hard rule for not including an action. For example,

```
Given I am at some bakery
When I place an order for some cake
Then I get an invoice for my order
```

Here, the Given statement can have both scenarios, of the tester having to go the bakery, or being already at the bakery. Therefore it depends on how the test specification and/or test automation services requires the scenario to be setup.